# Javascript loop giving me problems

Tags: javascript

I want to extract only groups from this string

I want to have something like  in alert "group1,group2"
 but it returns empty.

```
var phone_nos = "group1,group2,564774890900";   
var recipients = phone_nos.split(",");  
for( var i=0; i<recipients.length; i++ )
 group =recipients[i].substring(0,5)
{ if (group=="group")
         {groups.push(recipients)}


    }
    alert(groups.join(","))
```

Comment: `for (...) statement { block }` is probably not doing what you expected it to do. Put the statement *in* the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some misplaced braces for the `for` and assuming you want to filter `group*` you need to add `recipients[i]` the `groups` array rather than the original `recipients` string.

```
var phone_nos = "group1,group2,564774890900";   
var recipients = phone_nos.split(","); 
var groups = [];
for (var i=0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
  group = recipients[i].substring(0,5);
  if (group == "group") {
    groups.push(recipients[i]);
  }
}
alert(groups.join(","))
```

Modern browsers/IE9+

```
var groups = phone_nos.split(",").filter(function(v) {
  return v.substring(0, 5) === "group"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an error of sorts.

```
for( var i=0; i<recipients.length; i++ ){
    group =recipients[i].substring(0,5)
    if (group=="group")
         {groups.push(recipients)}
}
```

You for statement was only running the next line of code, not the block I think. If you format your code better you will be better able to see errors like this.

```
for( var i=0; i<recipients.length; i++ )
    group =recipients[i].substring(0,5)
   // MORE CODE
```

This above only runs the first complete line after the for.